# SecKeyCreateWithData always returns nil in iOS 17

Tags: swift, security, keychain, ios17, eos

When I'm trying to create SecKey using SecKeyCreateWithData it returns nil in iOS 17 (it's still working fine on iOS 16.4) with following error:

```
var attributes: [String: Any] = [ kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom, kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate, kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256, kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: accessGroup, kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true, kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [ kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true, kSecAttrAccessControl as String: access ] ] 

guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(privateKey as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, &error) else { print(error.debugDescription) throw EosioError(.keyManagementError, reason: error.debugDescription) }
```

Error:

> Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<__C.CFErrorRef>(_value: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "EC private key creation from data failed" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=EC private key creation from data failed}))

privateKey is base64Encoded Data `BNcHWtSeaQzOjwoHakZ66ojCFZV4uGU+VjRSAMOxd2NpwAEXHOarCV3yonOyJI5UIkJ1CCO+DbORtG83DDMkNuVmPGQu5nJiQCD9RfDA+UncG+woRrTrLDhAw6fHXD9DtA==`

Any other options of creating a SecKey or the possible resolution of this problem? It's became critical for our organization cause we cannot proceed with storage process and EOS accounts are becoming unavailable for all our users.

Comment: It appears your data is somehow invalid. `CryptoKit` tells me the reason is that the key has an "incorrect key size". Maybe there are some bytes missing somehow? Where did you get this key from?

Comment: Yeah, I got a response from Apple. It's EOS private key. The reason of that fail is K curve encryption that is using for private key representation. R curve works fine but we don't support that.

Comment: Also Apple: "Note that Apple CryptoKit will also fail to import this key, but the error in that case is more confusing (.incorrectKeySize). We have a bug on file requesting that CryptoKit throw a better error (r. 115984576)."